# ngx translate can't be installed with angular 14

Tags: angular, npm-install, ngx-translate

I am trying to install ngx-translate in my project with this command :

`npm install @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader`

but in the console i get this error :

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: collabzone-ui@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@">=16.0.0" from @ngx-translate/core@15.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@ngx-translate/core
npm ERR!   @ngx-translate/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
```

here's my package.json :

```
  "name": "collabzone-ui",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "jest -c jest.config.js src",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^2.5.4",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.34.0",
    "@colorthief/colorthief": "^3.0.0",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^5.0.1",
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.15.1",
    "@stomp/stompjs": "^7.0.0",
    "@testing-library/angular": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/ckeditor": "^4.9.10",
    "@types/date-fns": "^2.6.0",
    "@types/prismjs": "^1.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "data-fns": "^1.1.0",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.31",
    "mapbox-gl": "^2.15.0",
    "mapbox-gl-geocoder": "^2.0.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-calendar": "^0.0.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.3.7",
    "ngx-mapbox-gl": "^9.1.0",
    "node-vibrant": "^3.2.1-alpha.1",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.0",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^14.2.2",
    "prismjs": "^1.29.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.10",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.7.11",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^13.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

ps : when I try npm install i get the same error , but i use `--force`

I know that it's a dependency problem but i don't know how to fix it, how can I know which version works with which version ??

Comment: Do not post pictures of text.  It makes the relevant parts of your question unsearchable for others.

Comment: Most angular packages have a version matrix, e.g. https://github.com/ngx-translate/core .  That said, your angular installation is messed up and your cdk version is on 16.  I'd downgrade and then install translate v14 and http-loader v7 assuming you have the rest of the dependencies working.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install @ngx-translate/core@14.0.0 @ngx-translate/http-loader@7.0.0`

Version matrix: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#installation

Comment: I tried this but i still get the same error

Comment: change `"@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5"` to `"@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0` and then run `npm install`

Comment: thank you that helped me ! after changing to "@angular/cdk": "^14.0.0 i was able to use : npm install @ngx-translate/core@14.0.0 @ngx-translate/http-loader@7.0.0